# Failed to use content url() to style an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caroufredsel

[image]

I'm trying to style the circled elements in the above picture. I would love to add a jsfiddle here, but because I'm using a plugin called caroufredsel and because of my limited knowledge of Javascript and jQuery, I don't think its possible for me to provide one. So sorry about that. But here is my CSS and HTML code:

```
<div class="list_carousel">
            <ul id="foo2">
                <li>c</li>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>r</li>
                <li>o</li>
                <li>u</li>
                <li>F</li>
                <li>r</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>d</li>
                <li>S</li>
                <li>e</li>
                <li>l</li>
                <li> </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#"><img src="image/images/carousel_control_03.png"/></a>
            <a id="next2" class="next" href="#"><img src="image/images/carousel_control_05.png"></a>
            <div id="pager2" class="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.list_carousel {
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin: 0 76px 30px 76px;
            width: 808px;
        }
        .list_carousel ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            display: block;
        }
        .list_carousel li {
            font-size: 40px;
            color: #999;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #eee;
            border: 5px solid #999;
            width: 180px;
            height: 250px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 6px;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        .list_carousel.responsive {
            width: auto;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        .clearfix {
            float: none;
            clear: both;
        }
        .prev {


            float: left;
            margin-left: -30px;
            margin-top: -140px;
        }
        .next {
            float: right;
            margin-right: -30px;
            margin-top: -140px;
        }
        .pager {
            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .pager a {
            margin: 0 5px;
            text-indent: -999px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: transparent url(image/images/carousel_control_10.png);
        }
        .pager a.selected {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .timer {
            background-color: #999;
            height: 6px;
            width: 0px;
        }
```

I tried to add both `background: url()` and `content： url()` to `.pager a` but nothing happened; I also tried to use `text-indent:-999px` to push the text away so the background would show but nothing happened as well. Also, here is the Javascript that came with the plugin; I don't know if it will help any but I will include here as well:

```
$('#foo2').carouFredSel({
auto: false,
prev: '#prev2',
next: '#next2',
pagination: "#pager2",
mousewheel: true,
swipe: {
    onMouse: true,
    onTouch: true
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb but I have to type out the answer to my question here. I was using the wrong image url all this time so it did not work. Content url() worked fine, I keep tying out (/image/carousel_control_10.png) instead of (../image/carousel_control_10.png). Haha boy do i feel dumb...